# Add missing columns in table from one database to other database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Have two database (SQL Server 2008) (DataA and DataB) both db have table with same name (Employee).

Employee table In DataA have 15 columns and Employee table in DataB have only 5 columns.

I would like to add missing columns in Employee table in DataB. 
Need a query to fetch the column name from the table in DataA and checks whether the column is exists in Employee table in DataB and then add the column.

Do we need to use WHILE loop to add all the missing columns from DataA to DataB or do we have any option to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to accomplish this, you can loop over each column based on DataA, check whether it exists in DataB and if not add it.

Comment: PS. If it's a one-time thing, wouldn't it be easier to just script the table from DataA and drop-and-create it in DataB? Or import the table?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make use of the below query. Is working fine with SQL Server 2012. I believe the same will work with SQL Server 2008.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50),DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @column_name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @datatype VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @Max INT

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM 
        [Database1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME ='MyTable'
EXCEPT
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM 
        [Database2].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME ='MyTable'

SET @Count =(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Table t)
SET @Max =0
WHILE @Count > @Max
BEGIN
    USE [Database2]
    SET @Max = @Max +1
    SET @column_name = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM @Table t WHERE ID = @Max)
    SET @datatype = (SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM @Table t WHERE ID = @Max)
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ' +@column_name+' '+@datatype)
END
```